# Sending Image from recycler view to Other Activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a one Grid `RecyclerView` with image , now I want when user click on the recycler View , RecyclerView image show in the `DetailActivity` .

This is my RecyclerAdapter :

```
public class AdapterRecyclerDars extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterRecyclerDars.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Modelars> arsha;
    private Context context;

    //========================================== constructor

    public AdapterRecyclerDars(ArrayList<Modelars> arsha, Context context) {
        this.arsha = arsha;
        this.context = context;
    }

    //========================================== ViewHolder
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        private TextView txt_grid;
        private ImageView img_grid;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            txt_grid = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_grid);
            img_grid = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_grid);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("img_id",img_grid.getId()); <== I don't know this
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
    //========================================== onCreateViewHolder

    @Override
    public AdapterRecyclerDars.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.grid_row, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    //========================================== onBindViewHolder

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //setText
        holder.txt_grid.setText(arsha.get(position).getars_name());
        //download image
        Glide.with(context).load(arsha.get(position).getars_img()).into(holder.img_grid);
    }

    //========================================== getItemcount

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return darsha.size();
    }

    //==========================================
    //==========================================
}
```

And This is my Fragment where RecyclerView Load :

```
public class Fragment_one extends Fragment {
    ArrayList<Modelars> arsha;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        RecyclerView recyclerAvalDab = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_frg_aval_dab);
        // recyclerAvalDab.setHasFixedSize(true);
        initializeData();
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3);
        recyclerAvalDab.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);



        AdapterRecyclerDars adapterRecyclerDars = new AdapterRecyclerDars(darsha, getActivity());
        recyclerAvalDab.setAdapter(adapterRecyclerDars);
        return view;
    }

    private void initializeData() {
        arsha = new ArrayList<>();
        arsha.add(new Modelars("1", R.drawable.z));
        arsha.add(new Modelars("2", R.drawable.s));
        arsha.add(new Modelars("3", R.drawable.r));
        arsha.add(new Modelars("4", R.drawable.f));
        arsha.add(new Modelars("5", R.drawable.a));
        arsha.add(new Modelars("6", R.drawable.ad));
        arsha.add(new Modelars("7", R.drawable.d));
        arsha.add(new Modelars("8", R.drawable.z));
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to pass only position using array[position]

Comment: hi piyush , how are you ?

Comment: @kianarahimi: Hi, have u tried my answer dear?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must not call setTag() on a view Glide is targeting

Comment: @kianarahimi Thank god. Well your images are dynamic?

Comment: no , as i show in my code , i load images from ArrayList in the fragment

Comment: At anywhere are you using setTag()? Check these https://futurestud.io/blog/glide-callbacks-simpletarget-and-viewtarget-for-custom-view-classes and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27640307/android-glide-how-to-download-and-cache-bitmaps

Comment: i don't know , i'm confused , please help , i fix it , but my problem still not solved!!!:(

Comment: @kianarahimi Checked the links i have mentioned. Still you didn't get then ping me. When you know very well my friend.

Comment: @kianarahimi: at which line getting issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this i think work :

Just add These line to your `ViewHolder` in your `RecyclerAdapter`:

```
   public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        private TextView txt_grid;
        private ImageView img_grid;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            txt_grid = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_grid);
            img_grid = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_grid);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent  intent=new Intent(v.getContext(),DetailActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("IMAGE", arsha.get(getAdapterPosition()).getars_img());
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

And in your `DetailActivity` write these code in `onCreate` method :

```
int img_id;

   if (bundle != null ){
            img_id = bundle.getInt("IMAGE");
            imageview.setImageResource(img_id);
        }
```

That's it :D

Answer (score -1):

> Sending Image from recycler view to Other Activity

Instead of using `img_grid.getId()` to get image in next Activity, use setTag method of `img_grid` ImageView to store image resource id with each cell like change `onBindViewHolder` method as:

```
  @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
     ....your code here 
    //download image
    int drawableID=arsha.get(position).getars_img();
    holder.img_grid.setTag(String.valueOf(drawableID));
    Glide.with(context).load(drawableID).into(holder.img_grid);
   }
```

Now pass `drawableID` to next Activity as:

```
intent.putExtra("drawableID",Integer.parseInt(img_grid.getTag().toString()));
```

v.getContext().startActivity(intent);

In `DetailActivity` Activity show image as:

```
int drawableID = bundle.getInt("drawableID"));
imageView.setImageResource(drawableID);
```

Comment: It say java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must not call setTag() on a view Glide is targeting

Comment: @kianarahimi: At which line getting issue?