# how to get the bitmap cached through Glide?

Tags: android, android-glide

I am using Glide library for displaying image from url in recyclerView ,

```
                Glide.with( context )
                        .load(url).placeholder(R.drawable.default_user_picture)
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                        .crossFade()
                        .into(iv);
```

but since I want to print the bitmap from my app , I also want to get the bitmap of the image cached by Glide, so How to get the bitmap if we specify the url of the image that is already Cached?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Glide: How to download and cache bitmaps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27640307/android-glide-how-to-download-and-cache-bitmaps)

Comment: Downloading is fine, i want the path of the already downloaded images in cache and instead of making an asynchronous call again, I want the bitmap directly from the Cache through URL. Is it possible?

Comment: @alkaaswal check this out: "Glide doesn't support directly accessing the cache by design. Cache is a transparent storage, meaning you don't need to know about it" https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/509
But see rest of the comment, the other information might be useful for you, cheers